# How do I check if a method was overwritten by a child class?

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding, introspection

I want to be able to check if a child class has overwritten a method. For example,

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        # Is there something following this sort of spec?
        print("overridden" if self.bar != Foo.bar else "not overridden")
    def bar(self):
        return 0
```

An inherited method that overwrites `bar` might be:

```
class Kung(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Kung, self).__init__()
    def bar(self):
        return 1
```

In this case, `Kung()` should print "overridden", but `Foo()` should print "not overridden".
Can I check whether `bar` was overwritten in the `__init__` of Foo *without* checking the return value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strange thing to do. I question the design that would require this. In any case, you *could* check something like:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            bar = type(self).bar
        except AttributeError:
            bar = None
        if bar is None or bar is Foo.bar:
            print("not overriden")
        else:
            print("overridden")

    def bar(self): return 0
```

This works because you are checking for `bar` on the *class objects*. If you use `some_instance.some_method` then that creates a *new method object on each invocation*, which is why your approach won't work.

Consider:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(self): pass
...
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar is foo.bar
False
```

However,

```
>>> Foo.bar is Foo.bar
True
```

Comment: The use-case is pretty strange. I have a dataclass-like object representing arguments to an argument parser with methods that I want to protect. Further detail is at https://github.com/swansonk14/typed-argument-parser/issues/12.

Comment: I think we'll end up allowing overriding, and just make sure attributes don't shadow methods. Either way, this is interesting!